# Task Trigger with two conditions

Tags: trigger, tasks

Please help, I am trying to write a task trigger for an Opportunity.  I could not create a workflow because one of the fields is a look up.  I would like to create a task to advise the user they changed the stage to 'Assigned to Agent' but did not add the agent to the opportunity.    Please tell me what I am doing wrong I am getting an error message that I can no use "And" operator.  Thank you

```
trigger AgentMissingO on Opportunity (after insert) {
    List<Task> OTask = new List<Task>();
    Task t;
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        for(Opportunity o: Trigger.new) {  
            if((O.Agent__c != null)&&(o.StageName = 'Assigned To Agent')){
                t = new Task();
                t.OwnerId=o.OwnerId;
                t.Subject='Missing Agent';
                t.Priority='High';
                t.Status='Not Started';
                t.Description='Hello, You forgot to add the agent to the opportunity. Please click on the opportunity name above and add the agent name. Thank you ';
                t.WhatId=o.id;
                OTask.add(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this as a validation rule.

Create the validation rule on Opportunity with the error criteria

```
isblank(Agent__c) && ispickval(StageName,'Assigned To Agent')
```

and this will prevent the users saving the record in the first place, you can give them a helpful error message.

Answer (score 2):

You have an assignment (that has a string type):

```
o.StageName = 'Assigned To Agent'
```

instead of an equality check (that has a boolean type that works with &&):

```
o.StageName == 'Assigned To Agent'
```

You will also need to insert the `OTask` list after the end of the `Trigger.new` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Doug's answer that you could more simply accomplish this with a validation rule, but if you must allow the opportunity to be saved and create the task due to some other requirement, you'll have to adjust your code slightly. Keith pointed out that you'll need to change the assignment operator to an equality check for StageName, but from your description, you also want to insert this task when Agent__c == null instead of != null.

I'll leave aside the best practice of removing logic from triggers and instead delegating to a class to handle the logic (thereby enabling you to control the order of execution for your logic, which is not possible if you have multiple triggers per object), your code should look something like this:

```
trigger AgentMissingO on Opportunity (after insert) {
    List<Task> OTask = new List<Task>(); //Create empty list of tasks
    for(Opportunity o: Trigger.new) {  //loop through Opportunities
        if(O.Agent__c == null && o.StageName == 'Assigned To Agent'){
            t = new Task(); //for each opportunity that meets the criteria, instantiate a new task and set its values below
            t.OwnerId=o.OwnerId;
            t.Subject='Missing Agent';
            t.Priority='High';
            t.Status='Not Started';
            t.Description='Hello, You forgot to add the agent to the opportunity. Please click on the opportunity name above and add the agent name. Thank you ';
            t.WhatId=o.id;
            OTask.add(t); //add the task to the list above
        }
    }
    if(OTask.size()>0){
        insert OTask; //if there are tasks to insert, do so here
    }
}
```